# Redirect Admin to different page and User to different Page

Tags: asp.net, .net, loginview

```
SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from login where Email =@username and Password=@password and Activated_User=1 and User_Type=1", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Login1.UserName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Login1.Password);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Rows.Count > 0)
        {            
                Session["UID"] = Login1.UserName;
                Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
        }
```

Hi I am new to .NET
Above code is for LOGIN page.
I want to redirect Admin and user to different pages respectively(dashboard.aspx and user-dashboard.aspx).
User_Type=1 means Admin and if it is 2 then it means USER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use this simple way

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection string");
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select User_Type from TableName", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds);

        if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int usertype = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["User_Type"]);

            if(usertype==1)
            {
               Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");
            }
          else if(usertype==2)
           {
               Response.Redirect("user_dashboard.aspx");
           }
       }
       else
       {
         //record is not in ur table
       }
```

Comment: @ Janki
It is givig error "Cannot find table 0." 
on line int usertype = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["User_Type"]);

Comment: @ Janki
That error is resolved. But now on each login it is redirecting me to dashboard.aspx
it should redirect admin to dashboard.aspx and user to user-dashboard.aspx

Comment: I have tried that but Variable usertype is getting value =1 only not 2.

Comment: check in ur databse by this query "Select * from TableName Where User_Type=2"  if there is record then it should display here.if not then enter record in ur database which have User_Type is 2.

Comment: I have run that query in database and it is returning me the value that is wanted. But in above code it is not redirecting to User-dashboard.aspx page. It is redirecting to only dashboard.aspx page.

Comment: I have put the above code(whole code) in :  " if (ds.Rows.Count > 0)" condition.
can you tell me if it that is the problem?

Comment: I have pasted the whole code for page. Can you please check and tell me if it is ok?

Answer (score 0):

So whats the problem in it? why don't you put User_Type in your database as a column in the table you are storing the user information and then retrieve its value and use it in switch condition to redirect the user to correct page.

For example

```
try{
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select User_Type from TableName where username=@user", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "PersonName";
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows == false)
                {
                    throw new Exception();   
                }
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    int Value = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
                }
               switch(Value)
              {
               case 1:
               Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");
               break;
               case 2:
               Response.Redirect("user_dashboard.aspx");   
               break;
                }
              }
            catch
            {
                Result.Text = "THE GIVEN ID IS UNAVAILABLE";
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply..
How can i use Switch in above code?
User_Type is column in db.

Comment: It is giving ERROR "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types" on line "int Value = Convert.ToInt32(row["User_Type"]);"

Comment: Sorry Bro, I don't have visual studio installed right now but anyways
try this my updated answer... I hope it should work.

Answer (score 0):

that is because @janki's is not using WHERE clause in the sql statement.
use something like `select User_Type from TableName where username=@user` instead of `select User_Type from TableName`